# how to receive a variable from $.get of function?

Tags: javascript, json

Help me please ...

I have two function  and question - as to me to receive the chartData variable as AmCharts:

```
$.get(
    "/ITN/TEST/chart_test_JSON_REQUEST/",
    {
        param1:'title',
        param2:'BTSnum'
    },
    function(data) {
        var s = JSON.stringify(data);
        var chart;
        var chartData = s
        alert(chartData)    
    }
);

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    var chartData ????????????????????????????????

    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;

    chart.write('chartdiv');
});
```

Comment: Could you format your code please. And you question in unclear.

Comment: Are you sure to want stringify the data you received via get? If you want to parse the JSON to make it a JavaScript type use `JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of [JavaScript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to get the data in the `chartData` variable using the callback function.

Note how in the callback the chartData variable is not preceded with a `var` statement. This means that the variable is not local and it references the same variable as the first `chartData` of the function.

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {
    var chartData;

    $.get(
        "/ITN/TEST/chart_test_JSON_REQUEST/",
        {
            param1:'title',
            param2:'BTSnum'
        },
        function(data) {
            chartData = JSON.Parse(data);
        }
    );

    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;

    chart.write('chartdiv');
});
```

Comment: Explaining why something works might be useful to the asker :)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse for the wrong formatting - when sending a question - already I understood and next time I will correctly format... (it is my first question)

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {
var chartData;

$.get(
    "/ITN/TEST/chart_test_JSON_REQUEST/",
    {
        param1:'title',
        param2:'BTSnum'
    },
    function(data) {
        chartData = JSON.Parse(data);
    }
);

var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;

chart.write('chartdiv');
});
```

I have errors :

chartData is undefined
JSON.Parse is not a function